# combine month and day into one date column

Tags: r

Using R, I'd like to combine into one column (date) the month nb (month) and the day nb (day) contained in two different columns and use the created column in a date format.

my data frame looks like this:

```
St Dep Month Day
A 2 1 1
B 2 1 1
B 2 2 1
A 5 1 1
A 7 1 1
C 2 1 1
C 5 1 1
```

And I want to add a column with something like "Jan-01".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this...

```
df <- data.frame( Month = sample(1:12 , 10 , repl = TRUE ) , Day = sample(1:30 , 10 , repl = TRUE ) )
df$Date <- as.Date( paste( df$Month , df$Day , sep = "." )  , format = "%m.%d" )

df
#      Month Day       Date
#   1      1   8 2013-01-08
#   2      1  17 2013-01-17
#   3      7  23 2013-07-23
#   4     11  21 2013-11-21
#   5      3  30 2013-03-30
#   6     12  15 2013-12-15
#   7      2  30       <NA>
#   8      7  10 2013-07-10
#   9      1  16 2013-01-16
#   10     8   1 2013-08-01
```

I got some NAs because I made up random dates, some of which don't exist, such as 30th Feb

Comment: OK, that's it! I don't want to have the year (the variable I'm interested in is a mean on 30 years) but I may find a way to not plot the year in my axe (I use ggplot2).

Comment: I suggest you look at the solution by @ndoogan and accept that instead, it seems to do *exactly* what you want.

Answer (score 11):

I assume here that by "date format" you just mean a string that looks like a date, rather than a proper date class in R.

```
data <- data.frame( Month=c(1,5,2), Day=c(1,2,3) )
data$MonthDay <- paste( month.abb[data$Month], data$Day, sep="-" )
data
#   Month Day MonthDay
# 1     1   1    Jan-1
# 2     5   2    May-2
# 3     2   3    Feb-3
```

Comment: @SimonO101, the OP says he wants something like "Jan-01" at the bottom of the post :).

Comment: @Arun I know, that's why I said this was a much better solution :-) But sometimes people don't always fully explain what they want.

Comment: I wanted a real date (but without the year) to use it as a plot axis... So, I suppose that in my case the first proposition was good.

Comment: @SimonO101, I understand. I wrote just because of the word "assuming".